# Como executar um efeito jquery UI sem perder o posicionamento do componente?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

A ideia é que a div fique **sempre** centralizada na pagina, mesmo executando o efeito, e este comportamento não é observado no **Firefox**, onde o componente aparece vibrando na esquerda em vez de vibrar onde está posicionado (embora esteja ok usando Chrome 35 e Internet Explorer 11).

```
<div id="divEsquerda" style="background-color:#ffd800; width:50%; height:200px; margin:auto;">  

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).click(function () {
            $("div").effect("bounce");
        });

    });

</script>
```

Meu codigo no [JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pataki/xuh67Loe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este comportamento é específico do Firefox (testei na versão 23) e aparentemente em versões anteriores do Internet Explorer (testei na versão 11 e funciona). No Chrome 35 também funciona ok.

Lendo os comentários desta resposta: [JQuery UI bounce effect aligns elements left in Firefox and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5081114/1274092), percebi um workaround que parece funcionar tanto no Firefox quanto no Chrome e IE 10:

Em vez de fazer o `bounce` diretamente no `div`, posiciona-o em outro div (um *parent*) e faz o bounce neste div pai. Assim:

Html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="divEsquerda" 
        style="background-color:#ffd800; 
        width:50%; 
        height:200px; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto">  
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).click(function () {
        $("#parent").effect("bounce");
    });
});
```

Veja o Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xuh67Loe/1/